# Asyncio.gather for big lists of tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a problem. I'm using `asyncio.gather(*list_of_tasks)` for processing tasks (uses many CPU and I/O). Previously for limit tasks running concurrently I used `Semaphore`, but now I have over 2000 tasks and asyncio.gather hang on start this tasks for over 10 minutes (all tasks starts and stop on semaphore).

Is it possible to process const amount of task at one time?

Comment: Hello, do you really need all the tasks to exist simultaneously? If the answer is no, you can try producer-consumers pattern https://stackoverflow.com/a/66724938/10311377 Check the answer and let me know if it is what you need

Comment: Yes, I think about it – finally I move all to rabbitMQ queue, for async processing. But before I want to process sample tasks for check results (AI project)